# Spring bean not injected in CXF Restful Service on JBoss6

Tags: spring, rest, cxf, jboss6.x, cxfrs

I am writing a CXF Restful service with Spring on JBoss 6. The Spring bean is not injected. Instead of showing gobs of code here, I have shared a sample project [here](https://sites.google.com/site/kenbase/misc/restservice.zip). My understanding is that the spring context is not creating the rest service class and hence the spring bean (CoreService in the project) is not injected. However the same works well in TomCat. I want to get it working on JBoss6.

Please share your thoughts and help me resolve the issue. Your help highly appreciated. Thanks.